Can a moving fluid be considered as a rigid body?
Suppose, there is a fluid inside a container and the container itself is moving with a constant velocity'v'. Since, the velocity of each and every particle of the liquid will be same, their relative seperation will be constant. Therefore, can we consider it to be a rigid body, since the very definition of a rigid body is a body where the relative seperation between the individual particles is constant?

By that definition of "rigid", you've answered your own question.

a rigid body is one that cannot deform.  Can a fluid be deformed?  Yes.

The general answer is NO but it depends for what purposes you want to "consider" it.  If you want to, for example, calculate kinetic energy, then yes.  If the container is much smaller than other elements of the problem, then you could probably assume it was a simple mass.
But if the problem involves things like rotations or collisions then NO, the container and fluid will behave differently than a rigid body.

The rigid body approximation only holds for the fluid during uniform motion.
In uniform motion, the fluid can be treated as a rigid body because all particles move with the same velocity, and their relative separation remains constant. There is no internal motion or deformation.
In non-uniform motion, the fluid cannot be considered a rigid body because relative motion arises between particles. This leads to deformation of fluids and internal flow due to shear forces.
Considering your case, the answer is yes. The container and the fluid inside it can together be considered a rigid body.
